# Override dblclick behavior in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

'fitToView' is triggered by default on viewer double click. What is the best way to override this behavior with my own handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to override the default double click handler:

```
NOP_VIEWER.clickHandler.handleDoubleClick=(mouseClickEvent)=>{
//...
}
```

You might also want to find out about `CanvasClickBehavior` config - it sets Viewer's response to canvas interaction to a set of preset options:

```
const config = {
        "click": {
            "onObject": ["selectOnly"],
            "offObject": ["deselectAll"]
        },
        "clickAlt": {
            "onObject": ["setCOI"],
            "offObject": ["setCOI"]
        },
        "clickCtrl": {
            "onObject": ["selectToggle"]
            // don't deselect if user has control key down https://jira.autodesk.com/browse/LMV-1852
            //"offObject": ["deselectAll"]
        },
        "clickShift": {
            "onObject": ["selectToggle"]
            // don't deselect if user has shift key down https://jira.autodesk.com/browse/LMV-1852
            //"offObject": ["deselectAll"]
        },
}

NOP_VIEWER.setCanvasClickBehavior(config)
```